Azure CICD pipelines
One of our customer is using the release pipelines with powershell code to deploy databricks notebooks ( dev-tst-uat-prd).
The way it is built is not really practical. So we have one workspace for multiple Business projects and therefore dedicated folders for each project in workspace ( project 1 projecct 2 project 3)
And current CICD pipeline will look into all of those folders and pick all the nested folders or files and will move them accross env.
Major problem here is this scenario:
Lets say code for project 1 and project 2 is approved, pushed and now code is in UAT env. But something happened and Business did not approve the project 2 to be pushed to production but project 1 needs to go to production. Here we have problem as if i trigger the piple all the code goes.
this is the code
$admin_dir = "/ADMIN/"
$data_dir = "/DATA/"
$data_project1 = "/Project 1/"
$data_project2 = "/Project 2/"
$data_project3 = "/Project 3/"



$nb_folders = @($admin_dir, $data_dir, $data_project1, $data_project3, $data_project3)

foreach ($nb_folder in $nb_folders) {

    if ($target_ENV -eq 'd') {
        Write-Host "The environment is dev, so we don't change resource names in notebooks"
    }
    else {
        $nb_dir = $build_dir + $nb_folder
        Write-Host "Changing variables in notebooks"
        $files = gci -File -Path $nb_dir
        foreach ($f in $files) {
            Write-Output $f.name
            for ($i = 0; $i -lt $replace_str.Count; $i++) {
            (Get-Content $nb_dir\$f).replace($replace_str[$i].Source, $replace_str[$i].Target) | Set-Content $nb_dir\$f
            }
        }

        if ($target_ENV -eq 'p') {
            foreach ($f in $files) {
                Write-Output $f.name
                for ($i = 0; $i -lt $prd_replace_str.Count; $i++) {
                (Get-Content $nb_dir\$f).replace($prd_replace_str[$i].Source, $prd_replace_str[$i].Target) | Set-Content $nb_dir\$f
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if ($target_ENV -eq 'd') {
        Write-Host "The environment is dev, so command for copying scripts from repo will be skipped"   
    }
    else {
        Import-DatabricksFolder -BearerToken $DatabricksToken -Region "westeurope" -LocalPath $nb_dir -DatabricksPath $nb_folder
    }
}

#-------------------------------
# Cleanup
#-------------------------------

#Remove-Item $nb_dir\*

YMAL code for that specific task:
steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'Deploy notebooks'
  inputs:
    targetType: filePath
    filePath: './$(drop)/Deployment Scripts/Databricks/ads_deploynotebooks.ps1'
    arguments: '-build_dir $(drop)/Databricks/notebooks'

Could there be a solution to this without making a duplicated CICD per project/path?
Is it possible if  ($target_ENV -eq 'u') env is UAT then user who is triggering the pipeline manually define the value of the $nb_folder variable?

Where is the variable $target_ENV from in your PowerShell script? Can you provide the detailed YAML of your pipeline?

@BrightRan-MSFT it is defined in Pipeline variables. I have this line in my powershell file ([string]$target_ENV = "#{ENV}#",) and then its picking actuall variable from pipeline variables. I have updated with YMAL code, specific to my task that does the notebook deployments

Based your script, the value of the pipeline variable ENV is not static (hard-code), and it can be manually specified/selected a value when user manually triggers the pipeline. Right? @Greencolor

@BrightRan-MSFT ENV is indeed hard coded variable, but the user does not pass it. Its defined in the pipeline variables. See the image  https://imgur.com/a/5H6u0zs

If the value of ENV is hard-code and is not changeable, in the PowerShell script, why do you need to detect whether the value is a different one? @Greencolor

@BrightRan-MSFT file ads_deploynotebooks.ps1 which is moving files from Devops repo to in each dedicated env is generic. so that is the reason why. Mainly it tries to check for which env the pipeline runs at this moment. if the dev then there is no need for that task.

How to check which env the pipeline is running currently, and how do you let the script to change the value of the ENV variable to be the current env? If the env value is detected when the pipeline has started running, it is not possible to let the user to manually specified the value to a variable based on the env value. @Greencolor

Whether only when the env value is 'u' needs the user to manually specified the value of $nb_folder? For other env values, it will use the default values of $nb_folder set in the script? @Greencolor

to you first question: i have the pipeline tasks per env (https://imgur.com/a/OffbZLM), when running the pipeline there is the task "set variables" which are predefined. once they are defined (one of them is ENV)    then I can use them in my powershell script ads_deploynotebooks.ps1.  So if I move from EMEA_DEV release to EMEA_TST  release my variables changes to according environemnts.

@BrightRan-MSFT to your second question: yes, thats what I want ( one correction not u but p for production. so when production is running  in this case if ($target_ENV -eq 'p') then my $nb_folder should be passed manually by the user who is running the pipeline

@BrightRan-MSFT one possible way to manage what I want can happen if the user who has to trigger the PROD release pipeline, will comment the porject variables in the ads_deploynotebooks.ps1, and deploy the pipeline. and then uncomment again for future deployments that need to propagate from dev. but I find it not practical.

I have posted answer for your demand based on the information you commented above. Check and try with it. @Greencolor

You can try to use a pipeline runtime parameter to let the user pass the custom value to the PowerShell script:

In your PowerShell script, define a PowerShell parameter for use when ($target_ENV -eq 'u').

param (
    [string] $custom_nb_folder
)

if ($target_ENV -eq 'u')
{
  # Directly use the PowerShell parameter $custom_nb_folder in this section.
  Write-Host "$custom_nb_folder"
  . . .
}


In the pipeline YAML, set a pipeline runtime parameter and pass its value to the PowerShell parameter defined in the PowerShell script.

parameters:
- name: custom_nb_folder
  type: string
  default: '/Project 1/'

steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'Deploy notebooks'
  inputs:
    targetType: filePath
    filePath: './$(drop)/Deployment Scripts/Databricks/ads_deploynotebooks.ps1'
    arguments: '-build_dir $(drop)/Databricks/notebooks -custom_nb_folder "${{ parameters.custom_nb_folder }}"'

By this way, every time when a user manually trigger the pipeline, he can specify a different value to overwrite the default value, otherwise the default value will be used.


UPDATE:
If you want to provide the users with a list of all the available values and let the users can select and pass one or more values into the PowerShell script, you can do like as below:

In the PowerShell script, define an array type parameter to receive the multiple values passed into the script.

param (
    [string[]] $custom_nb_folders
)

Write-Host $custom_nb_folders

foreach ($item in $custom_nb_folders)
{
    Write-Host "$item"
}


In the pipeline YAML, define an object type parameter to provide a list of all the available values.

parameters:
- name: custom_nb_folders
  displayName: 'Delete un-required and only keep required items:'
  type: object
  default:
    - '/ADMIN/'
    - '/DATA/'
    - '/Project 1/'
    - '/Project 2/'
    - '/Project 3/'

steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'Deploy notebooks'
  env:
    JSON_CONTENT: ${{ convertToJson(parameters.custom_nb_folders) }}
  inputs:
    pwsh: true
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      Out-File -FilePath nb_folders.json -InputObject "$env:JSON_CONTENT"
      $arr = Get-Content nb_folders.json | ConvertFrom-Json
      Remove-Item -Path nb_folders.json
      ./$(drop)/"Deployment Scripts"/Databricks/ads_deploynotebooks.ps1 -build_dir "$(drop)/Databricks/notebooks" -custom_nb_folders $arr

With this way, when the users to manually trigger the pipeline, they can manually delete un-required and only keep required items from the provided default list.



thanks alot for the solution, I will test it.  one question thos, is it possible to have multi selection for the custom_nb_folders? lets say project 1 and project 2?

@Greencolor, Do you want to provide a list of available values and let the user can select one or more of them?

indeed, lets say I have full list of those $admin_dir = "/ADMIN/"
$data_dir = "/DATA/"
$data_project1 = "/Project 1/"
$data_project2 = "/Project 2/"
$data_project3 = "/Project 3/" and user has to choose two of them Poject 1 and project 2.  so it will loop over those file paths

@Greencolor, any two items from the list, or must select "/Project 1/" and "/Project 2/"?

it could be the combiantion of any

@Greencolor, Okay, let me have a try, and will give you an update later.

@Greencolor, See UPDATE in my above answer.
